# Move pointer in cpp issue with convert to hex

Tags: c++

im a beginner in cpp,I have Pointer who points to a specific address and I want to move this pointer 12 byts (on dec) down.
for example:

```
    int x=12
    node<int>* p = (node<int>*)m1;
    p=p-x;
```

but the address is written as hex so im moving the pointer more then i want.
what is the best way to do it.
I thought to convert the x to hex and i get 'c' as a string and then im got stuck 
thanks!

Comment: What data type is x?

Comment: Beyond that, the pointer arithmetic needs several preconditions to even be well-defined. You need to add a lot more details before this is answerable. Please create a [mcve]. As it is, your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not moving more because the pointer is visually represented by its hexadecimal value, that is only a way to visualize pointers. Pointer arithmetics in C++ works a little differently than what you might expect. When you subtract from a pointer, you are subtracting a number of blocks having the size of what is pointed to by the pointer.

That means that `p=p-x` is essentially subtracting `x * sizeof(node<int>)` from the pointer and not just `x`. So to subtract 12 bytes from the pointer, you can cast the pointer to something that only takes one byte of memory, and subtract the pointer value, and then convert the pointer back to its original type. But be careful when doing something like this, if you end up pointing at something that is not of the desired type, or simply unallocated you are in trouble.

So to subtract 12 bytes, you would have to cast to for instance `uint8_t` before subtracting:

```
int* p = new int(0);
cout << "Size of int: " << sizeof(int) << " Pointer: " << p << '\n';
int* p2 = p - 12;
cout << "Subtracting 12 (integers) from pointer: " << p2 << '\n';
uint8_t* bp = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(p);
int* p3 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(bp - 12);
cout << "New integer pointer address: " << p3 << '\n';
```

Resulting output will be something like:

> ```
> Size of int: 4 Pointer: 0x5555af8d1c20
> Subtracting 12 (integers) from pointer: 0x5555af8d1bf0
> New integer pointer address: 0x5555af8d1c14
> ```

See this running here: https://ideone.com/uVTcsA